# Tag merge / synonym request: [maintainability] -> [maintenance]

Tags: support, status-declined, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Suggest to merge [maintainability](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintainability) (35 questions, no tag wiki) into [maintenance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance) (80 questions, tag wiki quoted below), and make them synonyms.

Tag wiki for *maintenance*:

> The activities that occur after deployment of a software system. This includes making modifications to released systems, training, operating, and transitioning to support organizations.

---

If for some reasons mentioned tags are better kept separate, then it would be desirable to write respective tag wiki to help reader decide when to apply one or another tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[maintainability tag wiki](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/maintainability/info) has been edited to help reader differentiate this tag from [maintenance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance).

Excerpt was set as follows:

> system quality aspect characterizing the ease of software maintenance

Tag wiki were set as follows:

> Maintainability is a system quality aspect characterizing the ease of software maintenance.
>
> Related Wikipedia references...
>
> Related tags: [maintenance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I don't have time right now (just passing through real quick), but I'd want to take a closer look at how these tags are used.

As words, they are very different things. Maintenance is a phase in the product lifecycle that exists after a system has been deployed. Although systems in a maintenance phase go through some form of requirements engineering, architecture and design updates, implementation, and testing, the way those are handled can be (depending on the circumstances and the type of system being developed) different than a new product that has not been released. Maintainability is a quality aspect of the system under development and applies anywhere in the lifecycle, from requirements through the maintenance phase.

It's possible to have questions about products in the maintenance phase that have nothing to do with maintainability, as well questions about maintainability for products that aren't in a maintenance phase yet.